# Validate XML-DSig by DVCS

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature

Is it possible to validate an XML message (with XML-DSig or XAdES signature) by a Data Validation and Certification Server (RFC 3029)? Should it understand XML signatures or not? Could it parse XML? Or message must be in a specific format to be validated by DVCS?

According to RFC 3029:

> ```
> DVCSRequest ::= SEQUENCE  {
>     requestInformation         DVCSRequestInformation,
>     data                       Data,
>     transactionIdentifier      GeneralName OPTIONAL
> }    
> Data ::= CHOICE {
>       message           OCTET STRING ,
>       messageImprint    DigestInfo,
>       certs             SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF
>                             TargetEtcChain
> }
> ```
>
> The requester fills the 'data' element as follows:
>
> - For a vsd service request, the requestor encapsulates a CMS
>      SignedData object in the value octets of the 'message' choice.
>      It is up to the requester to decide whether and how to provide any
>      certificate that may be needed to verify the signature(s) in the
>      signedData object.  A requester MAY add certificates to the
>      encapsulated signedData object or in the certificate list of the
>      request.

Does it mean that DVCS doesn't support XML-DSig? Message must be in a CMS SignedData format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [RFC 3029](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3029) compliant server must process [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Message_Syntax) SignedData format messages, not any sort of XML messages.

That being said, converting between ASN.1 and XML is a common use case.  A modern implementation would/should probably accept various types of input messages, not just CMS SignedData.

I believe that it's also important to note that RFC 3029 is of type 'experimental' and is now 12 years old.